# Php input field value inside jquery loop

Tags: php, jquery

```
for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
              var ItemId = arr[i];
              var ItemQuantity = OrderedItemNameQuantityPair[ShopIdNamePair[SelectedShopIndex]+"_"+GetShopItems[ItemId]] ;
              <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION["ItemIdQuantity"]))  
                {
                  $ItemIdQuantity= $_POST['ItemId'];    



                }
                else
                {
                  $ItemIdQuantity = 0;
                }
              ?>

              ItemtableData=ItemtableData+'<table class="id_td_ItemContent"><tr><td width="40%" class="OrderedItem">'+GetShopItems[ItemId]+'</td>'+'<td width="10%">'+'<input class="OrderedQuantity" type="text" maxlength="2" name="ItemId" value='+ItemId+'></td>'+'<td width="10%">'+'<input class="OrderedQuantity" type="text" maxlength="2" name="Quantity" value='+"<?php print $ItemIdQuantity; ?>"+'></td>'+'<td width="50%" class="AddToOrder">'+'<input type="Button" onClick="updatedata()">'+'</td></tr></table>';
            }
```

I want to get the input field value `ItemId` and assing it to `$ItemIdQuantity` variable.

But the code which i used after page refresh output is not coming.

Comment: Where do you want to put the result of `$ItemIdQuantity`?

Comment: Your PHP codes are loaded **before** JS. therefore, it won't loop as you wish. Also, the JS codes didn't set the session variable at all.

Comment: I want $ItemIdQuantity after php part. In alert it is ok.First time when page is loaded no session value will be there. At that time, else part is working fine. Only issue is after refresh i need take value avl in the input field. Input field value will be avl from db